# OLAP Database support HIJRI date?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

I want to know if the OLAP database support HiJRI dates , my data source is oracle database . if it is not support,  any workaround available?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to convert between Gregorian and Hijiri? Or are you trying to format a `date` or `datetime` value from the database in a specific format? Generally speaking, databases store dates as binary data and you then decide how to format them when you present them to the user. Can you show some relevant DDL, data and/or code to illustrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to create dimention in OLAP to filter factTable by Hijri dates.

Comment: I want to create Hijri Dimension has these atrributes [Year-semester-Quarter-Month-Day] in BI project. i am  using visual studio 2008, I want to filter data in fact table by Hijri Date Dimension.All data coming from oracle database (Just read only)